# Getting Firebase document with falsy values

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to fetch an entry from my collection that either contains a value of an item set to `false` or the value is simply not set at all. Is this possible through a firebase query?

So for example, this would be the query to get the value set to `false`:

```
return db
    .collection('myCollection')
    .where('someAttribute', '==', false)
```

But what if I also want to fetch the items where `someAttribute` is not set at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's currently not possible to check if some field is not present in a document.  The way Firestore indexes work is by checking known values against actual values in documents.  Missing values are not indexed.

You might want to consider pre-populating new documents with known existing values.  You could enforce this from the client with security rules, or by populating values after addition with Cloud Functions triggers.